# cocoon select2 ajax load of partial - select2 element doesnt load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, cocoon-gem

I have a rails app that uses cocoon

= link_to_add_association

to call the partial form

on the main form I have the coffee script to load all of the data for the select2 elements

when the ajax partial is inserted the select2 element doesnt appear. I need to instantiate it.

This is my form coffee/js

```
  $(document).ready ->
   $(".select2").each (i, e) ->
    select = $(e)
    options = {}
    if select.hasClass("ajax")
      options.ajax =
        url: select.data("source")
        dataType: "json"
        data: (term, page) ->
          q: term
          page: page
          per: 10
        results: (data, page) ->
          results: data
      options.placeholder = "Select a value"
      options.allowClear= "true"
      options.dropdownAutoWidth = "true"
      options.initSelection = (element, callback) ->
        data = {id: element.val().split('||')[0], text: element.val().split('||')[1]};
        callback data
    select.select2 options
    return
```

If I use the coocon - insert after binding to

```
  $('body').bind 'cocoon:after-insert', (e, inserted_item) ->
    $(".select2").each (i, e) ->
      select = $(e)
      options = {}
      if select.hasClass("ajax")
        options.ajax =
          url: select.data("source")
          dataType: "json"
          data: (term, page) ->
            q: term
            page: page
            per: 10
          results: (data, page) ->
            results: data
        options.placeholder = "Select a value"
        options.allowClear= "true"
        options.dropdownAutoWidth = "true"
        options.initSelection = (element, callback) ->
          data = {id: element.val().split('||')[0], text: element.val().split('||')[1]};
          callback data
      select.select2 options
      return
```

I get all elements on the page refreshed - naturally as I call all select2 objects. I didnt write this code for the select2 js.

All of the existing form elements are ok, but those elemeted added dynamically get refreshed - so they loose the values they have.

I want to only select the element added and make it work.

if i try

```
$('body').bind 'cocoon:after-insert', (e, inserted_item) ->
  $(inserted_item).find(".select2").select2
  return
```

It doesnt work either

Tried many options but my hair is thin now and I am needing help. JS is my arch enemy I really find it a pain .....

HELP!

Comment: $(inserted_item).find(".select2").select2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('body').bind "cocoon:after-insert", (e, inserted_item) ->
    select=$(inserted_item).find(".select2.ajax")
    options = {}
    if select.hasClass("ajax")
      options.ajax =
        url: select.data("source")
        dataType: "json"
        data: (term, page) ->
          q: term
          page: page
          per: 10
        results: (data, page) ->
          results: data
      options.placeholder = "Select a value"
      options.allowClear= "true"
      options.dropdownAutoWidth = "true"
      options.initSelection = (element, callback) ->
        data = {id: element.val().split('||')[0], text: element.val().split('||')[1]};
        callback data
    select.select2 options
    return
```

Omg. hours on this and then I get it ....